# SSH through Bastion server difference between relogin and proxy

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-tunnel

I am not very versed in the inner workings of SSH etc. so bear with me.
We are using a Bastion server through which people need to SSH to do their work. Normally this would be SSH to bastion and then SSH to some server.

My question is this: Is there a real difference (technical, performance and security) between using two logins (1 to Bastion 1 to server) and using the -W command with ssh to proxy?

So difference with doing:

```
ssh user1@bastion
ssh user2@server
```

and

```
ssh user1@bastion -W user2@server
```

(not sure if this second one has the correct syntax as I don't use it, but I think you get the idea)

The login is first with a certain user with loginname/password and the second to the server with keypairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of "relogin", the 2nd client is running on the bastion host.

- Either your keypair must be on the bastion, or you need to use SSH "agent forwarding" to give it restricted access to the keypair.
- Any TCP forwardings (`ssh -L`) must be set up twice – once when connecting to bastion host, once when connecting to the real server.
- In addition, the bastion host can technically see everything you type and everything you receive over that SSH tunnel.
- One advantage, however, is that you could use Mosh to connect to the bastion host (and regular SSH from there on).

When `ssh -J` or a proxy command is used, the 2nd client is running *locally*.

- This means that authentication *only* needs to happen locally.
- TCP forwards only need to be processed once.
- The bastion server only sees the encrypted SSH traffic, not actual input/output.
- However, this mode adds some extra overhead since you have SSH *in* SSH; both in terms of network traffic and CPU usage.